# How to create a self-referencing model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've found a bunch of previously answered questions, or articles, about self-referencing has_many relationships, but not that address what I'm trying to do. I have a model Group and a join model that's meant to keep track of information about the relationships between groups. Here's what they look like so far:

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :relationships
  has_many :relations, through: :relationships
end

class Relationships < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :relation, class_name: 'Group'
end
```

The answers I've found until now present something like that, and that works alright but isn't what I want. Because if I create a Relationship from Group A to Group B, A.relations contains B (because B is the 'relation' in the Relationship) but B.relations does not contain A (because A is the 'group' in the Relationship).

The relationships I'm modeling aren't hierarchical, which means I'd like them to go both ways. I'd hoped something like this might be possible, but I can't find any information:

```
class Relationships < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group_one, class_name: 'Group'
  belongs_to :group_two, class_name: 'Group'
end

class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :relationships, :through => (:group_one || :group_two)
end
```

I realize that won't work, but I'm trying to illustrate what I want to do. Ideally I'd like it if a.relationships came back with an array of every Relationship where Group A is in *either* the group_one_id or group_two_id column, and where a.relations likewise followed the same pattern. I'd use a custom validation to ensure that :group_one and :group_two never referred to the same Group.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for `Group` model:

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :relationships, foreign_key: :group_one_id
   has_many :relations, through: :relationships, source: :group_two
end
```

And this for `Relationship` model:

```
class Relationship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group_one, class_name: 'Group', foreign_key: :group_one_id
  belongs_to :group_two, class_name: 'Group', foreign_key: :group_two_id
end
```

And your migration should look like this:

Example for Groups table:

```
class CreateGroups < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :groups do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Example for Relationships table:

```
class CreateRelationships < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :relationships do |t|
      t.references :group_one, null: false, references: :groups, foreign_key: { to_table: :groups }
      t.references :group_two, null: false, references: :groups, foreign_key: { to_table: :groups }

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

With this in place, you can create groups and associated each other with specific group.

```
group1 = Group.create(name: 'Group 1')
group2 = Group.create(name: 'Group 2')
group3 = Group.create(name: 'Group 3')

group1.relations << group2
group1.relations << group3
```

Not running `group1.relations` should return both `group2` and `group3`

Comment: That's not working. I can see, sort of, the direction you're trying to point me in but when I try to refer to group1.relations I get an error because (I think) there's nothing in the Relationship model defining :relations. Also, did you mean to have both foreign keys in the Relationship model pointing to :group_one?

Comment: Can you tell me which error are you getting when try to access `group1.relations`?

Comment: ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError (Could not find the source association(s) "relation" or :relations in model Relationship. Try 'has_many :relations, :through => :relationships, :source => <name>'. Is it one of group_one or group_two?)

Comment: I tested what I presented there and it works. Check please what are you doing different from what I put here... I am pretty sure you are doing something different

Comment: I'm using *exactly* what you've put up there. I even created a new, empty application to make sure none of my other code was interfering. Same problem. As best I can tell the problem is the association is one-sided: The Group model declares it has many relations through the Relationship model, but the Relationship model doesn't define a relations attribute.